# Load Full Image Recyclerview Cardview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Thanks to @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI. I made it to get a new full image view. Unfortunately it is not showing the full image. Where could i be going wrong?. I have posted the Main Activity and FullImageViewer Java Code and the Xml for full Image. Kindly point me to the right direction. All of the depedencies are ok.

[image: Recyclerview Cardview]
[image: Full Image View]

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http://ny.com/uploaddownload/fetchallimages.php";

    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_data";

    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_tag";

    String Image_Time_JSON = "time";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                       RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageViewer.class );
                       intent.putExtra("img", "HTTP_JSON_URL");
                       startActivity(intent);

                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
            }
        });
    }
    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){
        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }
    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));
                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));
                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

FULLIMAGEVIEWER

```
package com.ny.fetchallimages;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.CustomTarget;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition;

public class FullImageViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullimageviewer);
        final ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        String url = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("img");

        //Glide library to load image from URL
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        img.setImageBitmap(resource);
                       }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

FULLIMAGEVIEWER.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/color1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `Empty Activity` and named (for example *FullImageViewer*) with the following :

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA:**

```
public class FullImageViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullimageviewer);
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        String url = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("img");

       //Glide library to load image from URL
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        img.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

On item click event you need to pass your **URL** to `FullImageViewer` activity

```
 if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullImageViewer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("img", "YOUR IMAGE URL HERE");
                    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

---

In your Gradle file add the following lines :

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mouaad-abdelghafour-aitali. This seems like it will work but it is not showing the full image. Kindly assist to get the image URL part.